# I have put Firebase Analytics into my Android app, but only user properties are not being measured

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

As the title says, I have the Firebase SDK and Firebase Analytics in my Android app, but the user properties are not being measured.

I have the SDK installed and am able to measure screen_view events, logging events, and event parameters with no problem, but only user properties are not being measured.
Only user properties are not reflected in the real-time dashboard.

Does anyone know the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can access your registered user properties from the [Custom Definitions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/user-properties?platform=android#:%7E:text=data%20from%20the-,Custom%20Definitions%20page,-of%20Analytics%20in) page of Analytics in the Firebase console. It shows a list of user properties that you have defined for your app. Note that user properties are primarily used to build Filters and Audiences. For a detailed report regarding your user properties, you may consider using [BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article). This would allow you to export the [raw, unsampled event data](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en) along with all of your parameters and user properties, and then you may create your own simulation based on the raw data for your analysis.